# Rebels taking a province at war

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm at war and a rebels army popped in an enemy's territory that I captured before.

**If I let them capture it, will it decrease my war score ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, it is no longer under your occupation and thus won't count for warscore nor would you be able to negotiate for it.

Comment: Additionally, if rebels capture the wargoal, then both sides are considered having lost it, neither one will receive ticking warscore. It's important if the goal is to hold a capitol, for example